# Make jQuery recognize content loaded after page completion

Tags: jquery

I have a  tag that when clicked loads in a  list which has different id's for each, which is all done in a separate php file and it is loaded through $.post.

The issue i am now having is that because it isn't loaded when the page was when i try and assign jQuery to the loaded content it doesn't pick it up?

All the jQuery is on the initial index page where content is being loaded into.

Please let me know if i have been unclear or you need more information,

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code that loads the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just event binding you are missing then look into event delegation with `.on`. It would looks something like this:

```
  $('#loadContainer').on('click', '#loadedElement', function(){
      //will work even if called before elements are loaded
  });
```

But if its much more than event bindings you need to wrap the relevant code in a function and call it AFTER the ajax load with the built in callback. Something like this:

```
 function relevantStuff(){
     //things needed by loaded content
 }

 relevantStuff(); // run right away incase you need parts or all of this before the content is loaded as well

 $.post('yourUrl.php', function(result){
      $('#loadContainer').append(result); //inject html into page
      relevantStuff(); //do the stuff after load
 });
```

Also if you are using ajax to 'get' html and 'load' it into the page, please consider using `.get` or `.load`.

Comment: I am fairly new to jquery so excuse my poor knowledge, but what do you mean by event binding? I am trying to make it so that inside the links there will be more <a> tags that will have a .click() bound to each that will send another $.post :)

Comment: `.click` binds the 'click' event to the `<a>`. That is an event binding.